# dynamic change of background in google charts

Tags: google-visualization

I use the google chart to represent the temperature trend during the year  (every hour of every day).
I use an aspx page to extract data from a database where a column contains daily temperature values and the graph is dynamically built using those data.
A second column contains three possible values (0, 1, 2) to indicate rainfall (2 = absent, 0 present).
I would like (but I have not succeeded so far) to dynamically change the background of the graph as a function of those values (for example white for value 2, light blue for value 1, blue for value 0).
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

you could use a `switch` statement to determine the color

```
var color;

switch (rainfall) {
  case 0:
    color = 'blue';
    break;

  case 1:
    color = 'lightblue';
    break;

  case 2:
    color = 'white';
    break;
}
```

see function `getColor` in the following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: loadPage,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function loadPage() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');
  data.addRows([
    [0, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 2],
    [3, 3],
    [4, 4]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  drawChart(2);

  $('input:radio[name="rainfall"]').on('change', function () {
    var selectedRainfall = $('input:radio[name="rainfall"]:checked').val();
    drawChart(parseInt(selectedRainfall));
  });

  function drawChart(rainfall) {
    chart.draw(data, {
      backgroundColor: getColor(rainfall)
    });
  }

  function getColor(rainfall) {
    var color;

    switch (rainfall) {
      case 0:
        color = 'blue';
        break;

      case 1:
        color = 'lightblue';
        break;

      case 2:
        color = 'white';
        break;
    }

    return color;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="radio" name="rainfall" id="rainfall0" value="0" /><label for="rainfall0">Present</label>
  <input type="radio" name="rainfall" id="rainfall1" value="1" /><label for="rainfall1">Rain</label>
  <input type="radio" name="rainfall" id="rainfall2" value="2" checked /><label for="rainfall2">Absent</label>
</div>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much WhiteHat for the quick response. Unfortunately, this is not exactly what I wanted (I explained to you badly) even if your answer is anyway useful. I did not try to change the color of the entire background of the entire chart but only the areas between the x axis lines. It is a line chart and data on the x axis is the date; if one day it rains, associated with the temperature will be the value 0 in the "rain" database column and I would like to see that in the specified area of ​​the chart this could be seen with a color variation then when it does not rain. I think there may be two solutions (but I was looking for a confirmation): A) change the style (color) of that area, if, of course, I can access code from that area; B) Use a combined graph (columns and lines) to associate the temperature variation to a line and associate with a column (always of the same height but of different color) the data of the 'rain' column. I hope I've been clear now. I'm sorry. Thank you for a patient answer.